# WordPress site does not display content

Tags: xampp

I migrated a live site to my system and ran it via xampp. I am unable to see the contents of the page ( I can see the page loads fine but no text is displayed and site keeps connecting to the live site). Please advice me what needs to be done. Thanks.

Comment: I already posted solution for this. It's a complete solution for website links and images etc. Check here. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162974/wordpress-live-site-images-not-displaying#answer-162976

Comment: If you move your website then you will need to change URLs and database.

Comment: Use [Velvet Blues Update URL's](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/). This topic has btw been handled a couple of times. You should search the site before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An over simplified version of doing this is to download [WordPress Serialized Search and Replace tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) And drop it onto your server go to the location of where you have uploaded it. Then simply search for your old url, and replace with the new. This will do this for every post type, post data and if your theme has settings it will also replace in the settings. Regards TTech

Second thing you could do is this method and start your move from scratch

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/  Download and install this plugin on server 1, active the plugin select it from the menu, run through the steps.

You will get 2 files, an installer and a file zip. upload both to server 2. go to http://yoursite.co.uk/installer.php and run through the steps

Bingo site has moved.

Comment: I already used this tool. Still facing the same problem.

Comment: In this case your database may have become corrupted. Step 1. is to open your wordpress config file wp-config.php and enable the repair function define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true); and save this. then visit http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php make sure you have a backup of your database using phpmyadmin before running this.